# Android: Как заменить CardView?

Tags: android, recyclerview, cardview

Внутри RecyclerView отображаются карточки. На карточке есть кнопка Детали. При нажатии нужно заменить карточку на описание. И в описании есть кнопка Назад, чтобы переходило обратно к списку. Думаю подменять фрагмент с RecyclerView на CardView. Как можно реализовать кнопку назад, чтобы список открывался на той же карточке? Или это лучше как то по другому сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать без подмены списка на фрагмент. Например используя `DialogFragment` или простой `Dialog` с полноэкранными стилями. Для того чтобы вызвать диалог и показать данные в адаптере можно сделать показ диалога:

```
val dialogue = Dialog(ctx)
dialogue.setContentView(R.layout.yourLayout)
Objects.requireNonNull<Window>(dialogue.window).setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
dialogue.show()
```

где `yourLayout` это разметка которая будет показана с детализированной информацией. Так же там можно будет сделать слушатель нажатий на кнопку крестика, и при нажатии вызывать:

```
dialogue.dismiss()
```

и вы будете на том же месте откуда вызывали этот диалог. Это будет даже проще чем пилить через `DialogFragment`. Если все-таки вам нужно сделать через фрагменты, то нужно сделать интерфейс между адаптером и фрагментом где этот список лежит:

```
interface openCard{
    fun cardopen(pos:Int)
}
```

дальше делаем implement этого интерфейса и переписываем этот метод:

```
class YourActivity: AppCompatActivity(),openCard{
...
override fun cardopen(pos:Int) {

}
...
}
```

и так же в конструктор адаптера нужно будет передавать информацию о том что к активности (фрагменту) подключен этот интерфейс:

```
YourAdapter(..., this)
```

и потом в фрагменте в конструкторе уже будет интерфейс с методом:

```
openCard.cardopen(position)
```

этот метод нужно будет вызывать там где вы нажимаете на карточку. И дальше делаете замещение фрагментов в фрагменте где находится список,  передавая в фрагмент детального просмотра данные про карточку и позицию с которой вы уходите, а потом когда вам нужно будет вернуться в фрагмент со списком, то в bundle снова передавайте позицию и скрольте список до нее. Но лично мне кажется что через диалог будет проще :)

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать замену с помощью visibility. У нас есть recycler_view_item и он у вас содержит cardviev. Просто рядом с ним поставьте ещё один layout где будет уже описание и сделайте его visibility.gone  .  И потом в onclicklistener для показа карточки или описания просто  меняйте значения visibility из gone  на visible или наоборот.